# Changing the State Inside a React Component with using Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm fairly new to Redux and using it with a React Application. I'm currently coding a Multiplayer Space Strategy Game. I have the redux set up and I have the state called inside my component, but I cannot seem to figure out how to change the state from a onClick inside a button. Below is code: First(The initial State Reducer), Second(Another Reducer to hold the new state), Third(Counter and CounterAction and index) Fourth(The component that the state change will be happening in).

```
    import uuid from 'react-uuid';
const initalState = [
  {
    userId: 1,
    name: 'metal-mine',
    level: '0',
    productionAmount: '250',
    energy: '5',
    amount: '0',
  },
];

const metalMineReducer = (state = initalState, action) => {
  // const { type, payload } = action;

  switch (action.type) {
    case 'METAL_MINE':
      state = {
        ...state,
        level: state.level + action.payload,
        productionAmount: state.amount + action.payload,
        energy: state.energy + action.payload,
        amount: state.amount + action.payload,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default metalMineReducer;
```

2nd

```
const currentMetalMine = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'METAL_MINE':
      return {
        ...state,
        metal: action.payload,
        loggedIn: true,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default currentMetalMine;
```

3rd

```
const counter = (state = 1, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'INCREMENT':
      return state + 1;
    case 'DECREMENT':
      return state - 1;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default counter;
```

3.2

```
const increment = () => {
  return {
    type: 'INCREMENT',
  };
};

const decrement = () => {
  return {
    type: 'DECREMENT',
  };
};

export default {
  increment,
  decrement,
};

3.4

import counterActions from './counterActions';
import metalMineActions from './metalMineActions';

const allActions = {
  counterActions,
  metalMineActions,
};

export default allActions;
```

Component state will be changed in

```
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Button, Col, Container, Row } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import MetalMine1 from './MinesImages/Metal-Mine.jpg';

export default function MetalMine() {
  let metal = useSelector((state) => state.metalMine[0].level);
  let currentMetalMine = useSelector((state) => state.currentMetalMine);
  let counter = useSelector((state) => state.counter);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  console.log(metal);
  return (
    <Container>
      <Row>
        <Col>
          <br />
          <h4
            style={{
              color: 'whitesmoke',
              display: 'flex',
              justifyContent: 'center',
            }}
          >
            Metal Mine Level: {metal}
          </h4>
          <br />
        </Col>
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Col style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
          <img src={MetalMine1} alt='Metal Mine' height='300px' width='300px' />
        </Col>
      </Row>
      <br />
      <Row>
        <Button
          variant='outline-dark'
          style={{ color: 'whitesmoke', fontSize: '20px' }}
        >
          Upgrade
        </Button>
      </Row>
      <br />
    </Container>
  );
}
```

so after looking back at some documentation I have this updating the state in the component, but I need it to change the state and increment by 1.

```
export default function MetalMine() {
  let currentMetalMine = useSelector((state) => state.currentMetalMine);
  let counter = useSelector((state) => state.counter);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const [metal, setMetal] = useState(useSelector((state) => state.metalMine));
  console.log(metal);

  const increment = () => {
    setMetal((counter) => counter + 1);
  };



  return (
    <Container>
      <Row>
        <Col>
          <br />
          <h4
            style={{
              color: 'whitesmoke',
              display: 'flex',
              justifyContent: 'center',
            }}
          >
            Metal Mine Level: {metal.level}
          </h4>
          <br />
        </Col>
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Col style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
          <img src={MetalMine1} alt='Metal Mine' height='300px' width='300px' />
        </Col>
      </Row>
      <br />
      <Row>
        <Button
          onClick={increment}
          variant='outline-dark'
          style={{ color: 'whitesmoke', fontSize: '20px' }}
        >
          Upgrade
        </Button>
      </Row>
      <br />
    </Container>
  );
}
```

**DATA that needs to change the LEVEL***

```
{userId: 1, name: "metal-mine", level: 0, productionAmount: "250", energy: "5", …}
amount: "0"
energy: "5"
level: 0
name: "metal-mine"
productionAmount: "250"
userId: 1
```

when I click upgrade on the metal mine it's adding 1 to the end of the object, but not updating the object.
[image: adding 1 to the end of the object]

I hope that someone can help me figure out how to change the state. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: you need to dispatch the call to your action in the callback for your `onClick` handler

Comment: How would that look like given the code I have inside my question? I could really use a example.

Comment: im not sure what the payload should be to your action, what specifics you want to change when they click upgrade... etc. But. you should have an `onClick` handler on your button element. the callback function should `dispatch(setMetalMine(yourPayloadHere))`. that should run the action and update your reducer. the component will update with the new values that your selectors are pulling out

Comment: So If i'm understanding you correctly I create and clickHandler function. Then use the `dispatch(setMetalMine(yourPayloadHere))`. Then it should update the state?

Comment: Well the specific data that needs to change is the Level inside the state.
` import uuid from 'react-uuid';
const initalState = [
  {
    userId: 1,
    name: 'metal-mine',
    level: '0',
    productionAmount: '250',
    energy: '5',
    amount: '0',
  },
];
`

Comment: I have updated my question.

Comment: 3 things - 1) your "first" reducer is not returning state when matched with METAL_MINE - cant just say `state = something`, have to return it.  2) your initialState is an array of objects but your METAL_MINE then decides it is now just an object.  3) best practice for redux state here would be two things - a map/object of the objects using their IDs as keys and then an array/list of the IDs.  see the redux docs for why/how/more info https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add an `onClick` handler to your button, that will call `dispatch`:

```
<Button onClick={() => {
   dispatch(setMetalMine(...))
}} />
```

I'm not sure what this button should do, but this is how you dispatch an action, so you can adapt it to your needs

Comment: the callback should be in a `useCallback` handler for performance reasons, and use the action `setMetalMine`. dispatching a direct payload like that isn't a good idea

Comment: Thanks, I'm too used to `useReducer`... I tried to keep the answer as simple as possible. Also, in my opinion performance optimizations should be used when needed, not everywhere